# Need help to installing Ubuntu without losing Windows 10 Data

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, 20.04

I would like to install Ubuntu without losing Windows drive data.

Here's my Window 10 Setup:

- C Drive (SSD 250GB) [Wherein installed Windows 10]
- D Drive (2TB Data)

**I can fully format the C drive. Once I install Ubuntu's latest OS, can I get D drive access?** Or I'll lose all data of drive D?

**In D drive, I have important Softwares, photos, games, and data (.EXE and windows format files). Will I lose it?**

Is there any option or way to install Ubuntu without losing it?

I'm already using LibreOffice, 7Zip, GIMP, etc. I'm not using any Windows software anymore. Hence, I would like to move on permanently in the Linux world.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu on the SSD there is no reason for it to touch anything on the HDD but be careful, the installer will do what you tell it to. You mention important softwares on the HDD. They may not work under Ubuntu

Comment: "important" you say? So you understand the concept of backups?  Then why do you ask?

Comment: You should be able to read the content of your D drive on Ubuntu. That depends on which file sytem you are using.

Comment: @Jerare Please elaborate.

Comment: @Rinzwind Forget about 'important software', how about photos, videos, music, and other files? Where can I store that data for future reference?

Kindly note that I'm talking about permanently move on to the Linux platform. Hence, I need to keep everything with me.

Comment: Same answer: create a backup before messing with partitions. Get a 2TB external disk.

Comment: @Rinzwind - As per your guidelines, I need to move all data into a 2TB external drive. But my data is already safe into that drive (it's separate).
Imagine: I have installed Ubuntu in an SSD. The way I want to know that is, how can I connect that 2TB data in newly installed Ubuntu?
There are photos, videos, music, photoshop files, excel sheets, exes, and other files. Can I directly connect that drive with Ubuntu? I need the right way to do it safely.